# Adding Open Type Fonts to a Private Font Collection using Add Font File method

Tags: powershell, fonts

This is my first question here on stack overflow. I hope someone can help me. I need to add a large collection of Open Type Fonts to a private font collection object so I can extract the font name from each of the otf files. This will allow me to check if the font is already installed on a target system. Instead of checking the file names which is not reliable.

Here is my code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$path = "\\Themis\Fonts\*.*"
$otffiles = Get-ChildItem $path
$fontCollection = New-Object System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection
$otffiles | ForEach-Object{
$fontCollection.AddFontFile($_.fullname)
}
$fontcollection.Families
```

The above code works perfectly on Windows 10. However if I run this same exact code on Windows 7 I receive a "File Not Found" exception which I understand is thrown when the font file is not supported. I cannot believe that Windows 10 supports this method of dealing with otf files and Windows 7 doesn't. Am I missing something? Is there another way to skin this cat?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it is because you are using a network share. Try copying the files locally first and then read from there and let me know what happens.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to reply to my question. I did try your suggestion to copy the fonts locally. I created a folder called "Fonts" in the root of C:\ and tried the exact same code above except I set $path = 'C:\Fonts\*.*'. I get the same result on Windows 7. "File not found" exception. Works fine on Windows 10. Weird right?